# C# - EMGU CV taking frames with higher resoultion?

Tags: c#, image-processing, webcam, emgucv

I am trying capture frames with higher resolution (eg. 800x600) and brightness using EmguCV(emgucv 2.1.0.793).

I am using *A4 Tech PK-730MJ* Web Cam.

I tried to set capture property like this `_capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 600);`

But it always capturing 640x480 frame. How to set the frame capture, brightness property? Is this capture property camera specific? If yes, What camera should I use? Will Logitech Webcam Pro 9000 work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you solved the problem. For anyone who might be interested, you can only set it to one of the default resolutions, e.g 1280*1024, 600*480. I guess 800*600 is not one of the default settings. Try setting the height to 1024. It works for me. ^ ^

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = capture.QueryFrame().Resize(1024,768,Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR).Copy();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track!

Using [Emgu.CV 3.2.0.2721](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Emgu.CV/3.2.0.2721) You really should use:

```
VideoCapture Camera = new VideoCapture(0);
Camera.SetCaptureProperty(CapProp.FrameWidth, 1280);
Camera.SetCaptureProperty(CapProp.FrameHeight, 720);
Camera.SetCaptureProperty(CapProp.Autofocus, 39);
Camera.SetCaptureProperty(CapProp.Fps, 60); // 60Fps for USB 3.0, 30 Fps for USB 2.0!
```

This will solve your problems, changing the Default Resolution: 640 x 480 to the HD Resolution you set for your Camera.

See: [CapProp Enumeration](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.5.1/document/html/766b735b-77fa-f092-3d40-21545a7d0d8f.htm)